# android: play segment of Lottie animation

Tags: android, lottie

I think the title of the question says it all,

I though of adding an animation Listener but couldn't get the result i want.

```
     //lottie_toggle is the view id

     lottie_toggle.addAnimatorUpdateListener {valueAnimator->
        val progress = (valueAnimator.animatedValue as Float * 100).toInt()

        if (progress==100 ){
            lottie_toggle.cancelAnimation()
            lottie_toggle.progress=0f
        }
        if (progress==50 ){
            lottie_toggle.cancelAnimation()
            lottie_toggle.progress=0.5f
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It sets the maximum progress that the animation will end at when playing or looping.

```
lottie_toggle.setMaxFrame(maxFrame);
```

It sets the minimum frame that the animation will start from when playing or looping.

```
lottie_toggle.setMinFrame(minFrame);
```

It sets the minimum and maximum frames that the animation will start and end when playing or looping.

```
lottie_toggle.setMinAndMaxFrame(minFrame, maxFrame);
```

Answer (score 0):

it appears that setting the min/max frame is a suitable way,

```
//if the animation has 60 frames
lottie_toggle.setMinAndMaxFrame(0,30) //to play the first half
lottie_toggle.setMinAndMaxFrame(30,60) //to play the second half
```